# woocommerce redirects back to cart after checkout, and shows empty cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce, I am trying to build a shopping page where user can select more than one product at a time.once the user selects the products then i am posting the productids from the page to the cart.php file of woocommerce.There , I have added products to cart using,

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($productid[$i]);
```

programmetically on the cart.php file of woocommerce plugin.
It correctly shows the products in the cart, but once I press "checkout", it redirects to the cart again, but this time, the cart is empty.
And further, if I login and do the same process, the checkout works correctly.

Comment: Try disabling all other plugins, and reverting to a default theme. I don't think what you are describing is default behavior so I suspect something is interfering.

Comment: this issue is coming when i try to add more than one product in a loop, issue is not there when i login and proceed, i tried using xmlhttp.open("GET","http://expressleads.net/cart/?add-to-cart="+autoid,true), gives the same problem,works well for adding one product to cart at a time, not multiple.

Comment: Please edit your question then to explain what you are specifically trying to do. What you have tried so far. What result you are getting from that. And how that differs from your goal. Clearly this is a more in-depth problem than your question would suggest.

Comment: Same problem. Seen it elsewhere too. Any fix for this?